# Transparent Background in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

On Ubuntu, I can change the terminal background to be semi-transparent.  I've seen other people do this in OSX, but I don't see the setting anywhere.  Is there some way to make this happen?

Comment: Apple UI has gone down the toilet: reduced contrast, reduced font size, smaller buttons, and forced menu bar items. Time to put the adults back in charge of UI design.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you select the color picker for the Window - there's an opacity slider there:

[image]

Comment: +1 - Thanks very much. I've been searching too and it never occurred to me to look there.

Comment: Only setting Opacity (Deckkraft) and Cmd-N to open a new termnial made no difference. I do get to choose a background color and it applies directly to the TotalTerminal window, but no effect on new non-TotalTerminal windows.

Comment: It's not clear form this answer how to get to the window above.

Answer (score 6):

1. open Terminal
2. in menu bar: Terminal > preferences > profiles > text > Background > color & effects
3. you will get something like this:

   [image]
4. play with different blur values
5. Enjoy