# Saving Terminal Color/Opacity Preferences

Tags: terminal

My question is related to this question:
[Transparent Background in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13502/transparent-background-in-terminal)

I have successfully found the menu to change color/opacity. I used the "homebrew" profile. Then I attempted to change the opacity as shown in the answer. However, once I put the opacity at 100% and closed the window, it completely ignored my changes and went back to 90%. How do I actually ensure that my preferences are saved? There is no "OK" or "apply" button on the color menu.

Comment: I tried reproducing your result but couldn't. When I set opacity to 100% it stays. What version of macos are you running?  My Terminal version is 2.8.3l.

Comment: it says:
Version 2.8.2 (404)

Comment: Actually, it appears that *double-clicking* on the color and effects option somehow makes it go back to 90% ? I don't understand fully why this happens. I single-clicked it and it appears to work now.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking once (and only once) on the "color and effects" icon and adjusting the opacity should properly save any adjustments. Double-clicking may have caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while, but for profile changes like making Homebrew your profile, double click the option as there is nowhere to 'save' on this on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I could make the opacity setting stick this way with MacOS 10.14 (Mojave).

First, with a Terminal window open, I selected `Shell -> Edit Background Color` and there used the Opacity slider. This changed the opacity for the active window.

Then I selected `Shell -> Use Settings as Default`. This changed the opacity in all open windows. New windows now also have the desired opacity.

Answer (score -3):

My contribution is more of a help, not really a solution, but maybe you could use it. What if you have changed the appearance of the terminal but you don't really like it? With this code you can reset it at any time.

```
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist; killall Terminal
```

Comment: The question is about how to save preferences, not about how to reset/remove them.